# I need an idea to print the value of a particular column that is present in 150 tables.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the max date value of 150 tables. I don't want to write a separate sql for each of those 150 tables. Is there any way to put all the 150 table into a single query and print 150 max date values? Thanks!

Comment: So, do you have a field of type date in 150 different tables?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: Can you provide some details so we know what you are trying to do. It seems that most people think you want a single result but your question sort of indicates it might be one row per table. Is the column name consistent across all the tables?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps with a little Dynamic SQL

Clearly you can edit the WHERE to fit your needs.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='>>>'

Select @SQL = @SQL +' Union All Select Source   ='''+QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'
                   +QuoteName(TABLE_NAME)+''',FieldName='''+QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME)+''',Value=max('
                   +QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME)+') From '
                   +QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QuoteName(TABLE_NAME)
 From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 Where COLUMN_NAME Like '%UTC%'
   and DATA_TYPE in ('date','datetime')

Select @SQL=replace(@SQL,'>>> Union All','')
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns For Example**

```
Source                      FieldName   Value
[dbo].[OD]                  [OD-LM-UTC] 2016-11-03 20:28:09.987
[dbo].[zzz-OD_XP]           [XP_LM_UTC] 2016-07-22 22:53:37.113
[dbo].[zzz-OD_OH_Archive]   [OH_LM_UTC] 2016-01-22 15:07:39.077
[dbo].[OD-XP]               [XP-LM-UTC] 2016-11-03 21:28:28.113
[dbo].[USPS-Full]           [LM_UTC]    2016-07-20 15:03:53.600
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a UNION of the 150 tables and get the MAX date value.  The only way to avoid manually entering all 150 tables, though, is with dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
select max(maxd) from (
    Select max(date_column) as maxd from table1
    union 
    Select max(date_column) as maxd from table2
    union 
    ....
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely out of the question to manually *union* all your tables. The trick will be to use Dynamic SQL.
Say your table names are TABLE1 to TABLE150.

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @n int = 1;
WHILE (@n <= 150)
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'SELECT MAX(Date_col) as Max FROM TABLE' + convert(nvarchar(3),@n) + ' UNION '
SET @n += 1
END
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL) -6) --Removes the last 'UNION '

EXEC @SQL
```

What you want to do next is to adjust the value of @n so that if reflects the name of your tables.
Best of luck.

Comment: I guess you're doomed then

Comment: If they are uniform names like this I would suggest using a tally table instead of a loop but wouldn't make any noticeable difference on so few iterations.

Comment: @SeanLange, I just googled what is was, it looks SO NEAT I'm glad you commented !

Comment: Here is an excellent article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ This has been referred to as the "swiss army knife of t-sql" because it is so versatile.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max),@maxid INT,@minid INT,@Runquery VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE @Maxdatefind TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Slcmd VARCHAR(max))  

SET @Sql='

SELECT 
''SELECT  MAX(''+COLUMN_NAME+ '')''+'' AS ''+''MAX_''+COLUMN_NAME+'' FROM '' +QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+''.'' +
QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE IN (''datetime'',''date'')
'

PRINT @sql
INSERT INTO @Maxdatefind (Slcmd)
EXEC( @Sql)

SELECT @maxid=max(id),@minid=min(id) from @Maxdatefind

WHILE (@minid <@maxid)
BEGIN

SELECT @Runquery= Slcmd from @Maxdatefind where ID=@minid
EXEC(@Runquery)
SET @minid=@minid+1
END
```